# Facebook shairing to feed & Recent activity

Tags: facebook, share

Is there any method to share the post to feed and recent activity only. The post should not be shown on a users Timeline.

Comment: No there is not. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @WizKid This was a requirement in one of the projects that i am doing. I could not find anything matching my requirement. So i posted my doubt here so that i can be sure.